# Rendering linkbutton with image

Tags: development, asp.net, html

I have an issue when i try to render the linkbutton with image and text it isn't rendered correctly. I render it from a servercontrol in method OnLoad.
And I do not understand why, maybe someone knows the problem.

Here is the code:

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
            builder.Append("<div>");               
            builder.AppendFormat("<asp:LinkButton runat='server' id='someid_{0}' OnClientClick='{0}_perfrom();'>", this.ClientID);
            builder.AppendFormat("<span><span><img style='border:0' id='SomePic_{0}' src='/_layouts/images/mypict.png' />", this.ClientID);
            builder.Append("Text</span></span></asp:LinkButton>");
            builder.Append("</div>");

            this.Controls.add(new LiteralControl(builder.ToString()));
```

The result is:

```
<div>
  <asp:linkbutton id="" runat="server" /> //here by some reason the tag is closed
    <span>
    <span>
    <img ....>
    Text
    </asp:linkbutton /> //and also here
  </div>
```

Any idea, why such a strnge behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

this is not the way u can add server side control in code-behiend

you can do something like this

```
        TextBox txtname = new TextBox();
        HtmlTable tbltop = new HtmlTable();
        HtmlTableRow row1top = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell cell1top = new HtmlTableCell();
        // apply style like that
        cell1top.Attributes.Add("Style", "color:#1C1156;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;");


        cell1top.Controls.Add(txtname)
        row1top.Cells.Add(cell1top);
        tbltop.Rows.Add(row1top);

        this.Controls.Add(tbltop);
```

you can do same thing using div also.

Comment: What is this? Sorry but this is far from what i'm looking for. just adding a table to page ... why?

Comment: look code i am adding textbox a server control in table cell and then add table in page

Comment: why -1? please describe

Comment: see this :- same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666072/how-to-generate-server-side-tags-dynamiclly

Comment: Shkipper: He is saying is that you cannot add server side controls like that, and its probably not far from what you are looking for :)